# Node.js http.get response in loop

Tags: node.js

So I have following code. This code must create 3 graphs, but only creates 1 (last):

```
for (var b=0; b<routers.length; b++)
 {
    for (var a=0; a<rout.length; a++)
    {
       if(something==something)
       {
           console.log("bla bla");
           var options = {
               host: 'xxx',
               path: '/xxxxx
               port: 'xxxx'}                    
            http.request(options).end();
            http.get(options, function (response) {
                response.setEncoding('utf8') 
                response.on('data', function (data) {
                    var responseArray = JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log("we get data. we create graph!!!"
                })         
           })
       }
    }
 }
```

So if I run script I get first 3x "bla bla" and then after this 3x "we get data. we create graph!!!". I think in my case it must be "bla bla" and "we get data. we create graph!!!" and so on for 3x. Am I right?? I am new in node.js so please help me.

Comment: Javascript i asynchronous. Is there any reason they have to come in order. Having them wait will just increase loadtime. You could use callbacks or a flow control library like async to control the flow.

Comment: Use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Answer (score 0):

Promises are *one* pattern for doing this, not the only one.  Whether they're the best pattern is subject to a lot of debate in the community.  The other options include async.js and using an EventEmitter.  For something like this, I tend to prefer Async.js, but I've used all three patterns.  I also prefer request.js to the built-in http client, because it's a little easier to use.

Here's a simple example using request.js and async.js:

```
var request = require('request'),
    async   = require('async');

function iterator(router, next){
  var options = {}; // however  you build your options argument
  request.get(options, function(e, response, data){
     if(e) return next(e); // something went wrong with the request

     var json = null;
     try { json = JSON.parse(data); }
     catch (err){ next(err); // handle errors on parsing }

     // if you get here, parsing happened just fine. 
     console.log('parsed this router:');
     console.log(json);
     next(); 
  });
}

function handleFinalResults(e){
  if(e) return console.log('Dangit, ', e.message);
  console.log('Successfully got everything');
};

async.each(routers, iterator, handleFinalResults);
```